# Set up default sound player

Tags: r, wav

By using R packages like tuneR and seewave I generated sounds that I want to play with some software that is not Windows Media Player but I don't know how to set this up. This command

```
setWavPlayer("mplay32")
```

Is the only thing that works (and its WMP). When I try something like this

```
setWavPlayer("C:/Program Files/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe")
```

The synth or play command just gives this error when I try to playback my sound

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what works for me under OSX: assuming I've installed an app called 'play.app' ,

```
setWavPlayer('/applications/play')
```

In your case it would appear that somewhere along the line your path string's space (in "Program[space]Files" ) is causing the string to be split up.  That error message is pretty clearly coming from a CommandPrompt or similar shell.  You need to quote the string using `shQuote` so that the space is handled properly:

```
setWavPlayer(shQuote("C:/Program Files/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe"))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what Carl is suggesting is to replace "Program Files" with "Program\ Files" (i.e. the backslash before the space).

Comment: I get the same error even when I escape my spaces: `setWavPlayer("C:/Program\ Files/Windows\ Media\ Player/wmplayer.exe")`.

Comment: I think you can also pass the quotes along as follows:  `setWavPlayer(' "C:/Program Files/foo.exe" ') `

Comment: The quotes passing as Carl suggested worked and now I can play with seewave. Thank you.

Comment: The function to quote strings to be passed to the OS is `shQuote`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in windows this is what I did. Unfortunately wmplayer does not work perfectly. Nonetheless you can play sounds with it.

```
  setWavPlayer('"C:/Program Files/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe"')
```